# How to provide y and n continues response command to shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Have a sample script and wants to execute only one at a time, so how can I provide the command line input to the shell script to execute the response?
Also, I can not modify the script, here from below code only wants to execute "ls" command.

```
have tried below command to execute, but it took 'yes' for both

yes yes no | bash test.sh
```

```
e.g:
while true; do
  read -p "Would you like to run ls command? (y/n)" response
  case $response in
    [Yy]* ) ls; break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo; echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
  esac
done

while true; do
  read -p "Would you like to run PWD command? (y/n)" response
  case $response in
    [Yy]* ) pwd; break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo; echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
  esac
done
```

Can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From description of `yes`:

> Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'

so, `yes yes no` outputs:

```
yes no
yes no
yes no
...
```

but you want

```
yes
no
```

You could try to put a newline in your string:

```
yes 'yes
no' | bash test.sh
```

Or, as you only need it once and not repeatedly, feed it to your script manually:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' yes no | bash test.sh
```

Comment: printf '%s\n%s' yes no | bash test.sh worked, thanks

Comment: `echo yes no | bash test.sh` is even simpler